# Updating notification on android sometimes doesn't update

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using a job intent service to download my image database, while this happens I display a notification informing the user how many images are being downloaded which ones succeed or fail and when the service finishes, the logs seem to show everything happens exactly as it should but it often fails to update everytime for instance heres my logs showing the correct calls happen in the correct order:

```
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.CreateDb NOTIFICATION_ID 102
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 1
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 2
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 3
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 4
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 5
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 6
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 7
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 8
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 9
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 10
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 11
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 12
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 13
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 14
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 15
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 16
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 17
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 18
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 19
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 20
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 21
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 22
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 23
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 24
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 25
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 26
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 27
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 28
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 29
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 30
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 31
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 32
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 33
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 34
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 35
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 36
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 37
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 38
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 39
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 40
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 41
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 42
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 43
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 44
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 45
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 46
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 47
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 48
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 49
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 50
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 51
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 52
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 53
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 54
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 55
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 56
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 57
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 58
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 59
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 60
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 61
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 62
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 63
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 64
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 65
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 66
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 67
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 68
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 69
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 70
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 71
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 72
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 73
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 74
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 75
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 76
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 77
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    D/CreateDb: count 78 success 78
    D/CreateDb: FINISHED
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101
    D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.CreateDb NOTIFICATION_ID 102
```

but the image below shows that the notification only updated 75 times, this seems random the logs are consistent but the notification often fails at or around 77, 76 or 75 and also often works just fine. I use the same manager, I call sendNotification with a notification id a channel id a title and if it should show a progress, I haven't tried using the same builder yet does anyone have any ideas?

```
        private NotificationManager getManager() {
            if (mManager == null) {
                mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            }
            return mManager;
        }

        private void sendNotification(int NOTIFICATION_ID, String CHANNEL_ID, String title, boolean progress) {

            Log.d(TAG, "CHANNEL_ID " + CHANNEL_ID + " NOTIFICATION_ID " + NOTIFICATION_ID);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = getNotification(CHANNEL_ID,
                    title, progress).setOngoing(progress).setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
            getManager().notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

        }


        private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotification(String channelId, String title,
                                                        boolean progress) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
            notificationBuilder
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_logo_notification)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setChannelId(channelId)
                    .setProgress(0, 0, progress);

            return notificationBuilder;

        }
```

[image: notification evidence screenshot]

this is how it looks when it works
[image: correct working]

added title to the logs ran service again this time it stopped updating the notification at 74

```
    020-03-09 08:18:33.247 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101 title Downloading, 75 of 78 images.
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.580 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/simple/simple_why_large.png
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.581 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/ImageHelper: resizedBitmap h: 129 w: 134
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.582 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: count 78 success 76
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.582 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101 title Downloading, 76 of 78 images.
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.624 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/original/photo_why_large.png
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.629 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/ImageHelper: resizedBitmap h: 142 w: 120
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.631 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: count 78 success 77
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.631 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101 title Downloading, 77 of 78 images.
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.634 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: SUCCESS for core/images/quicks/pronouns/photos/photo_why_large.png
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.645 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/ImageHelper: resizedBitmap h: 142 w: 120
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.646 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: count 78 success 78
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.646 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: FINISHED
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.656 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.DownloadDb NOTIFICATION_ID 101 title Downloaded all images.
    2020-03-09 08:18:33.660 29017-29017/com.sealstudios.simpleaac D/CreateDb: CHANNEL_ID com.sealstudios.simpleaac.CreateDb NOTIFICATION_ID 102 title Finished Creating Sentences
```

Comment: You might want to add `title` to your `Log.d()` call in `sendNotification()`. Perhaps there is a bug in how you are preparing that value, and `title` would appear to be where your problem lies.

Comment: when the count matches the success and failure count it calls a finish method which should update these notifications to show finished but it doesnt always work

Comment: I cannot comment on that, as your question does not appear to have that code. It is also possible that notification updates are not processed FIFO, so your updates might all get applied, just out of order, if you are sending them too quickly. You might try updating the notification every few seconds (and then only if the data changed) and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare added the title to the log message ran the service again, it again fails to update the notification stopping at 74 this time but the logs look fine added new logs above, as you can see the title is updated to show finished and downloaded for both notifications

Comment: changed it to update the notification every ten images or when finished and it now works every time